# PIL OSError when importing custom truetype font

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've installed a font (burbank.ttf) that I am trying to use in PIL. I double-checked, and it is installed, but I get an error when running the code below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.open('blended.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('burbank.ttf, 15')
draw.text((256, 76.8), "test", font=font)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Item Shop/txttest.py", line 5, in <module>
    font = ImageFont.truetype('burbank.ttf, 15')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 640, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 637, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

I've tried specifying a direct path to the font, which doesn't work. I don't know much about fonts, but I converted the .otf file to .ttf in order to use it with PIL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('burbank.ttf, 15')
```

to

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('burbank.ttf', 15)
```

If it couldn't solve your problem.
One possible reason:it couldn't find the path of `burank.ttf`,try to give all the path of your font.

Comment: worked perfectly. can't believe i didn't see it myself :) ty